# Unable to load the kernel module 'nvidia.ko'

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ati, gpu, oracle-linux

On my system I'm unable to install the recommended graphics driver, so something must be wrong with my installation.

The GPU chipset is ATI ES1000, but the recommended driver is NVIDIA NVS300 downloaded from the server vendor's site.

> The maximum graphics resolution of the onboard graphics controller ATI
>   ES1000 with the native driver of Microsoft Windows 2012 is 1280 x
>   1024. ATI has not planned to support ATI ES1000 graphics chip with Windows 2012. So there"s no OEM driver available which could be
>   installed on PRIMERGY TX100 S3 or TX100 S3p with Microsoft Windows
>   2012. For higher graphics resolutions on PRIMERGY TX100 S3 or TX100 S3p, the PCIe graphics controller NVIDIA® Quadro® NVS 300 can be used.

Before installation I switched to runlevel 3 (`init 3`) and blacklisted nouveau driver (`echo blacklist nouveau > /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf`). None of the conflicting drivers is present:

```
# lsmod | grep -e nouveau -e rivafb -e nvidiafb
(empty)
```

These are all steps that should be needed, what else can be wrong on my Oracle Linux (based on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.7, Kernel Linux 3.8.13-118.2.1.el6uek.x86_64, GNOME 2.28.2), I was thinking incompatible kernel or some GPU driver conflict?

List of OS supported by the driver:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.6 (x86_64)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.7 (x86_64)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 GA (x86_64)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.1 (x86_64)
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3 (x86_64)
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4 (x86_64)
```

The main error:

> **ERROR: Unable to load the kernel module 'nvidia.ko'.  This happens most frequently when this kernel module was built against the wrong or
>   improperly configured kernel sources, with a version of gcc that
>   differs from the one used to build the target kernel, or if a driver
>   such as rivafb, nvidiafb, or nouveau is present and prevents the
>   NVIDIA kernel module from obtaining ownership of the NVIDIA graphics
>   device(s), or no NVIDIA GPU installed in this system is supported by
>   this NVIDIA Linux graphics driver release.**

Output from `/var/log/nvidia-installer.log`:

```
-> Kernel module compilation complete.
-> Unable to determine if Secure Boot is enabled: No such file or directory
ERROR: Unable to load the kernel module 'nvidia.ko'.  This happens most frequently when this kernel module was built against the wrong or improperly configured kernel sources, with a version of gcc that differs from the one used to build the target kernel, or if a driver such as rivafb, nvidiafb, or nouveau is present and prevents the NVIDIA kernel module from obtaining ownership of the NVIDIA graphics device(s), or no NVIDIA GPU installed in this system is supported by this NVIDIA Linux graphics driver release.

Please see the log entries 'Kernel module load error' and 'Kernel messages' at the end of the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for more information.
-> Kernel module load error: insmod: error inserting './kernel/nvidia.ko': -1 No such device
-> Kernel messages:
survey done event(5c) band:0 for wlan0
==>rtw_ps_processor .fw_state(8)
==>ips_enter cnts:5
===> rtw_ips_pwr_down...................
====> rtw_ips_dev_unload...
usb_read_port_cancel
usb_read_port_complete()-1284: RX Warning! bDriverStopped(0) OR bSurpriseRemoved(0) bReadPortCancel(1)
usb_read_port_complete()-1284: RX Warning! bDriverStopped(0) OR bSurpriseRemoved(0) bReadPortCancel(1)
usb_read_port_complete()-1284: RX Warning! bDriverStopped(0) OR bSurpriseRemoved(0) bReadPortCancel(1)
usb_read_port_complete()-1284: RX Warning! bDriverStopped(0) OR bSurpriseRemoved(0) bReadPortCancel(1)
usb_write_port_cancel 
==> rtl8192cu_hal_deinit 
bkeepfwalive(0)
card disble without HWSM...........
<=== rtw_ips_pwr_down..................... in 29ms
usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 7
usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=093a, idProduct=2510
usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 2-1.2: Product: USB Optical Mouse
usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: PixArt
input: PixArt USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/input/input7
hid-generic 0003:093A:2510.0005: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [PixArt USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0
NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!
NVRM: NVIDIA init module failed!
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

Comment: what makes you think an nvidia driver is appropriate for an ATI (aka AMD) GPU?  That will never be the case, nvidia and ATI/AMD are competitors and do each other no favours.  The ES1000 is an old GPU without 3D support, and AFAICT isn't supported by (and doesn't need) the radeon driver. See http://askubuntu.com/a/381651/75909

Comment: It says it can be used for my specific server model (TX100 S3P). The NVS300 driver is even available on the vendor's download page for my speficic server: http://support.ts.fujitsu.com/WDB/FAQContent.asp?ID=233489832&Info=Fulltext&Sprache=EN&LNG=COM&LNID=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ES1000 is built-in to your motherboard, the NVS300 is an optional extra.  Which is why are you getting an error message saying `NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!`

The text you quoted says that if you want higher resolution than what the ATI ES1000 supports, then you can install an Nvidia NVS300, which is a completely different and separate GPU card.

The NVS300 is also a fairly old card. you could probably install any other recent AMD or Nvidia card that would physically fit into the slot (would need a pci-e x16 slot) and into the case (you might need a small fanless card).

e.g. an Nvidia GTX-750 (around $110USD) completely wipes the floor with an NVS300, it's so much faster that it's beyond comparison - and the 750 isn't even close to a top-of-the-range modern GPU.   Even much cheaper cards like the ~$40USD GT610 are significantly faster than the NVS300.

According to http://www.fujitsu.com/tw/Images/ds-py-tx100-s3-en.pdf
 your system has 1 pci-e 3.0 slot that is physically x16 (so it can take a full size x16 GPU card) but only x8 electronically, so the card would run fine but with slightly reduced bandwidth (GPUs don't use anywhere near the full bandwidth of pci-e 3.0 @ x16 anyway).

Finally, if you just want the ES1000 built-in GPU to work, it should Just Work with a reasonably modern linux kernel and X. Don't expect high resolution or fast graphics, though.

Comment: The ES1000 card currently supports respolution up to 1024x768, so I'm using it as a headless server. If there was a driver that would support at least 1280 something it would be usable, but according to the support page it does not.

Comment: The limit is not in the driver, it's the hardware.  if you want higher resolution, you'll have to install a GPU card in one of the slots.  If you don't care much about high-speed 3D graphics, get a ~$25USD GT210 or ~$40USD GT610.  The nouveau driver built-in to the kernel should be fine for most 2D desktop use and light 3D use with those cards, or you could install the proprietary nvidia driver - oracle linux probably has a dkms package for it.

Comment: The maximum of the ATI with a native driver is 1280x1024, but to me it still gives 1024x768. The thing is that the newer ATI drivers don't work with this one.

Comment: how much is your time worth?  for ~$25 you could have an nvidia gt210 that just worked, and it has a max resolution of 2560x1600 and (depending on brand) DVI, VGA, HDMI and/or DisplayPort connectors.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is written in the log:

```
No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!
NVRM: NVIDIA init module failed!
```

You cannot load nvidia driver if you do not have a NVIDIA card on your computer.

The main error message you have noted about kernel module building is generic. It does not apply in your case, where the error message is clear.